# How can photos in one flickr account be "seen" in another one?

Tags: flickr

I took 382 photos for a martial arts school that my children attend, opened a flickr account and created a set for them. The school has its own flickr page, which is linked from the school's website. The owner would like to have my photos "seen" from the school's flickr page rather than a publishing the link to mine.

I'm trying to figure out how he can have my photos on the school's flickr page. The only real option I see is for him to reload them directly to the school's account. I thought about the "group" option, with the school the owner and me adding my photos to his group, but I'm not sure that viewers would see the group without having to go looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to transfer your photos across from your account to the schools account.  I'm not sure this is possible to do within the web UI.

I think the best option would be to email Flickr support directly and provide them with all the relevant details. They should be able to transfer the photos for you.

Alternatively, you could try [Migratr](http://www.callingshotgun.net/about/migratr/).

> Migratr is a desktop application which
>   moves photos between popular photo
>   sharing services. Migratr will also
>   migrate your metadata, including the
>   titles, tags, descriptions and album
>   organization.  Whether you want to
>   copy your photos from Flickr to Faces,
>   Picasa to Phanfare, or Zenfolio to
>   Zooomr, Migratr is the app for you. 
>   Migratr will copy your photos FROM any
>   supported photo service, TO any
>   supported photo service.
>
> Currently, Migratr supports the
>   following services:
>
> - 23HQ
> - Aol Pictures (Import Only) (CLOSING)
> - Faces.com
> - Flickr
> - Menalto Gallery (Self-Hosted)
> - Picasa Web
> - Phanfare
> - Photobucket
> - SmugMug
> - Zenfolio
> - Zooomr

Answer (score 1):

Ask the school account to create a gallery that contains the top photos they want of yours to be seen.

> #### [What is a gallery?](http://www.flickr.com/help/galleries/#938178)
>
> For whatever you find interesting, fascinating, or mind-blowing on Flickr, galleries are a way to curate up to 18 public photos or videos of your fellow members into one place. It’s an opportunity to celebrate the creativity of your fellow members in a truly unique way around a theme, an idea or just because.

They just need to go to the photo page, click **Actions** and select **Add to a gallery**. If that option isn't available, it's because the photo/member has disallowed letting their photos from being added to galleries.

They'll still be on your account, but the school will also have a copy of them in a set of large thumbnails on their profile that they can link to instead.

If they click through for larger versions they will still go to your photo page though.